# Conditional removal when focusing out

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myText">
<div id="myDiv">
```

When a user focuses out of the text field, I would like to remove #myDiv, ONLY if the user focused out to an area which is not in the DIV itself.

So far I have the code to remove the div no matter where the user clicked on the screen. What do I need to add to the following code in order to prevent the removal of the div if the user click inside it?

```
$("#myText").focusout(function(evt) {
    $("#myDiv").remove();
});
```

Comment: are you talking about a click are about a focus event ? That is not the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.  When the blur event is fired, you can access the element that was focused and you can then check the id of the element to see if it matches the id on the div.  If it doesn't match, then remove the div.

```
$("#myText").blur(function(e){    
  var target = e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget||document.activeElement;

  if ($(target).closest("#myDiv").length == 0 && target.id != "myDiv")
    $("#myDiv").remove();
});
```

Here is a quick example I put together on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/iwari3/10
Let me know if that is what you are looking for

**Updated**
Since the original version wasn't working in Chrome, I decided to take a different approach and it seems to be working in IE/FF/Chrome.

```
var $myDiv = $("#myDiv"),
    $myText = $("#myText");

 $myText.blur(function(e){        
    if (!$myDiv.data("focused"))
      $myDiv.remove();

    $myDiv.data("focused", false);
 });

 $myDiv.mousedown(function(e){
    $(this).data("focused", true)
 });
```

This new method will now store a focused bit on #myDiv on mousedown which gets fired before the blur event.  In the blur of the textbox we check to see if the focused bit was set.  The focused bit is then reset back to false to handle cases where the textbox is clicked in and out of multiple times.

Here is an updated jsbin.com example: http://jsbin.com/iwari3/11

Comment: I'm looking into it.  I'll let you know if I find a solution for Chrome

Comment: Thank TB. I am trying too but no success so far :/

Comment: T.B. - it works! I want to thank you for the great answer and work :)  Just want to ask a little something - How come the "mousedown" event of the DIV is trigerred before the .blur event of the text? It seems like this really happens every time, but why does it happen?

Comment: In order for a blur to occur a click event (mousedown+mouseup) has to be fired outside of the element.  The mousedown will always occur before the blur since the blur is waiting for the mouseup event to occur.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can have a hidden field with a flag value .

on clicking inside div set the hidden field value to 1.

you should do this before you call remove();

before calling div check this flag and remove.

after removing unset the flag

Comment: That is a nice idea, but how can I guarentee that the click() event handler of the Div will be called before the focusout() of the text type, so it can change the flag in time?

Comment: @Matt i was thinking about storing value in JS , but there will be two functions , little confused about scope of the variable.     var a= 0; func set(){ a=1}  func unset() {a=0}. will work!!!

Comment: @Joel try to use onfocus  and focusout

Comment: For that I need to make sure that the click() is called before the focusout(). Is there anyway to do that?